# <ng-template> not rendering dynamically in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript, directive

.html file

```
<ng-template #temp1><p>some content</p></ng-template>
<ng-template #temp2><p>some content2</p></ng-template>
<ng-template #temp3><p>some content3</p></ng-template>
```

I want to render 1 of the above template based on some value which I am getting in ngAfterviewInIt().

Tried using TemplateRef and *ngTemplateOutlet   ,but nothing working

Comment: Hi Robin, please add the code of what you tried plus the error that you got, otherwise the answer has to be a tutorial about ng-template in general and that is not the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: I think you are missusing ng-template directive(refer to official docs for more info https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template). From your post it really seems that all you need is a bunch of if directives. Provide more context/code please

Comment: Sounds to me like you need [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch#usage-examples)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly then you want to display any one template conditionally then you can achieve by below ways:

```
<ng-template #temp1 *ngIf="<some condition>">
<ng-template #temp2 *ngIf="<some condition>">
<ng-template #temp3 *ngIf="<some condition>">
```

Comment: !!!ng-template by itself will not render!!!